# Flutter GETX - What is the difference between variable.value = newValue and variable(newValue)?

Tags: flutter, observable, flutter-getx, rxdart

I've always been thinking that in Flutter GetX library, if I have an observable variable defined in this way

```dart
Rxn<MyClass> myObsObject = Rxn<MyClass>();
```

I could update its value by doing:

```dart
myObsObject(newValue) / myObsObject(null)
```

or in an EQUIVALENT WAY

```dart
myObsObject.value = newValue / myObsObject.value = null
```

Today I discovered that the 2 methods are NOT equivalent, since doing the first way in some cases (don't know how to reproduce ATM) doesn't retrigger the builder of a `GetX` widget, while the second does.

So what is/are the difference(s) between the two methods up above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the implementation of the first way and you will see that it is this:

```
T call([T? v]) {
  if (v != null) {
    value = v;
  }
  return value;
}
```

So basically, it still does the assignment to `value` **except when the value is null**.

So `myObsObject(newValue)` should work fine in all cases except when `newValue` is `null`